# Where did accept rate go?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I used to always see my accept rate when I asked a question. Did this feature get removed or is it just not used when a certain reputation is reached?

Answer (score 2):

The accept rate has been removed as of January 22, 2013. This [was requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136951/205264) on Meta SO.

The community found it to negative, and it generated a lot of comments like "Perhaps you should first accept some answers", that [got removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110644/205264) anyway because they were found to be inappropriate.

Comment: That sucks.  Beside, if someone has a lot accept rate, then they *should* go back and consider accepting a few answers.  I have in the past not bothered answering someone with a low accept rate.

Comment: I had 0 percent for a while because I didn't know how to accept for like 3 months lol

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with answers not getting accepted - a real one, and a petty one.

The real one is that the question doesn't look as if it has been resolved.

The petty one is that the author of a good answer doesn't pick up that 15 points.  This prompts very low-rep users who really want those points to post comments soliciting an accept; for some that becomes a habitual badgering to have a low quality answer accepted just minutes after it was posted.  But those with a few thousand rep probably aren't going to care that much - and if the answer is good, its upvotes will total more than the accept anyway.

All in all, it's easily possible that the pettiness aspect was more serious than the lack of "resolution".

It would be nice though if there were some way that questions without an accepted answer would keep popping back up to get their asker's attention.  But some questions never get a good answer; so maybe there could be an "I saw it but it's not a solution" checkbox, so you'd only get a reminder about questions with answers which you had not "noticed" by either checking that box or commenting on.

Comment: You missed the third and most important problem with unaccepted question, which is that they then get periodically bumped back to the top by "community", even though the OP is long gone and doesn't see it. I do like your idea about the check box *None of these solved my problem*. That would put the question nicely to rest, at least until a new answer is added.  The system could than regularly (weekly?) nag users to do something with their limbo questions.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I noticed on SO.meta to be bumped they also need to have no upvoted answers. Some of the questions are pretty average which is why they don't get much attention but lately I've been upvoting answers on them if I feel it's about as good an answer as the question is likely to get so they don't keep coming back.

Comment: Getting bumped back to the top is part of the not looking resolved which I was calling the "real" issue.